# "Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'draggable' " after using AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

Im currently building a webpage using jquery, I have draggable divs in there. Everything works fine, except when I click one of those divs to send the indexes using AJAX. The page reloads again with the new data I get from MySQL but the events "draggable", "sortable" and "droppable" give the following error:

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'draggable' "
```

Everything works fine except those events.

Here are some examples of my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/calendar/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/validationPrescriptionNewConsole.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/calendar/jquery.datepick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/balloon/jquery.balloon.js"></script>

(...)

$('#padroes').children().each(
    function(index, elem) 
    {
         $(elem).click(function(){

        $.ajax
        ({ 
            url: '***same page***',
            data: {indice: index, dt_ini: datepick1.value, dt_fim: datepick2.value },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(output) 
            {
                $("body").html(output);     
            }
        });
    });
}); 
(...)

$(".jogos").draggable(
{ 
    cursor: "move",
    opacity: 0.7,
    revert: true,
    revertDuration: 50  
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you calling `$("body").html(output);` with the result?

Comment: I have a form that submits all my data when I click a button, but I just want to submit the indexes to get more data before I click the submit button so I use AJAX to refresh the page and that way I only get the isset of $_POST["indice"]. I cant put a form inside a form.

Answer (score 2):

Never define click functions in each handlers. Also, you're never stopping the default click event.

```
$('#padroes').children().click(function(e){  //add the e
    e.preventDefault(); //stop default behavior
    //your ajax call

});
```

Furthermore, you're using `$('body').html(output)` which is then overwriting all of the existing data in the body, so any handlers that were bound to these elements on page load will no longer have any methods associated with them. You'll need to redefine them in the `ajax success function`

```
success: function(output){
    $("body").html(output);
    $(output).find('.jogos').draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        opacity: 0.7,
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 50  
    })
}
```

This should resolve it.

Comment: @scott.korin Updated...Somehow the rest of my code was truncated from my post.

Comment: I just jumped the gun, then

Comment: I wanted to send the indexes thats why I used each instead of click right away

Comment: It doesnt solve the problem, gives the same error in this line. $(output).find('.jogos').draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        opacity: 0.7,
        revert: true,
        revertDuration: 50  
       })